# Taxonomy list with content counters

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

Using Drupal 7,

I have a content type: Movie,

It has a taxonomy of actors: Keanu Reeves, Christian Bale, Milla Jovovich, etc.

I'd like to build a view which lists the actors taxonomy with a count of content matching the taxonomy term, for example:

```
Keanu Reeves (4)
Christian Bale (8)
Milla Jovovich (2)
```

I'm not sure how to build this view,

I've set a view with use aggregation, filter: =published, content type=movie, lang=users language,

fields: COUNT(Content: Actors)

It doesn't seem to accomplish my goal, please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to implement via view, here's a custom block code to replace the view.

```
$vid = 3; //vocabulary id
$num_term = 8; //limit maximum terms

$query = "SELECT tid, name, count
FROM (
SELECT td.tid AS tid, name, COUNT(td.tid) AS count
FROM taxonomy_term_data AS td
JOIN taxonomy_index AS tn
  ON td.tid = tn.tid
JOIN node AS n
  ON n.nid = tn.nid
WHERE td.vid = ". $vid ."
  AND n.status = 1
GROUP BY td.tid
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT ". $num_term . "
) AS t
ORDER BY name ASC";

$result = db_query($query);
foreach($result as $term) {
if ($term->count > 0) {
  echo l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid").' ('.$term->count.')'.'<br/>';
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be way to generate the View you're looking for without having to do custom coding.  See if http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/01/20/drupal-7-get-number-of-nodes-of-taxonomy-term-in-views/ or http://dev.nodeone.se/en/the-aggregation-setting-the-emmajane-episode helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, it is possible to do this with Views. No coding or additional modules are required. See [How To Use Views Aggregator to Create Taxonomy Term Count Block?](http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-use-views-aggregator-to-create-taxonomy-term-count-block) for the recipe.